# Why is catch not handling this error C++

Tags: c++, exception

When I run this in linux machine, I expect the catch block to catch the exception. Whereas I get a segmentation fault. Why is this ? Should it not print "Caught exception"

```
void handle_eptr(std::exception_ptr eptr) // passing by value is ok
{
    try {
        if (eptr) {
            std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
        }
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Caught exception \"" << e.what() << "\"\n";
    }
}

int main()
{

    char *c =(char*) 0x10;



    std::exception_ptr eptr;
    try {
        std::string s = c;

    } catch(...) {
        std::cout<< "Caught exception";
        //eptr = std::current_exception(); // capture
    }
   // handle_eptr(eptr);
    std::cout << "Normal Exit";
}
```

Comment: [What exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)?

Comment: Should it not print "Caught exception"

Comment: your expectation is that an illegal address dereference will cause a c++ exception. This is not so. You have triggered UB, UB could do anything; including throwing an exception, turning on the lights on yr xmas tree, reformat yr hard drive, ...

Comment: C++ is not like Java - there are some undefined behaviors (UBs) that will cause the program to crash without an exception.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking why made-up language rules do not hold isn't going to produce valuable insights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given

```
char *c =(char*) 0x10;
```

the following line causes undefined behavior.

```
std::string s = c;
```

The behavior of your program after that can be anything. It's pointless to try make sense of the program's behavior after that.

More on undefined behavior can be found at [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: But there was a catch to catch the exception. I thought it should print "Caught exception" message and gracefully return

Comment: @Ram there is no exception to be caught. *Undefined behavior* does not throw an exception

Comment: @Ram, there is no guarantee that accessing memory that you are not supposed to must throw an exception. Some platforms might but then, that's also undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to initialize `std::string with` a `*char` who points to memory that is almost sure not for your program.
You get a segmentation fault which is not a C++ exception it is system exception.
C++ `try.. catch` blocks only capture C++ exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing a `std::string` with 0x10, where does that point? What you have is undefined behavior, which was luckily caught with a segmentation fault.  C++ does not require exceptions to be thrown for such undefined behavior.

A segmentation fault does not cause an exception to be thrown.  And that is why nothing is caught.

Comment: A segmentation fault is an exception. It is just not C++ exception it is system exception.

Comment: @PetarVelev I think its safe to assume that I meant a C++ exception in my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are thrown by `throw` statements. Random coding errors might result in accidentally throwing exceptions, but that is not required and not at all common.